# Reading from serial problems with Amazon FreeRTOS

Tags: c++, c, freertos, rtos, esp32

I am attempting to read from the uart2 on an ESP32 DevKitC clone on a task thread.

My code is as follows:

```
uint8_t data[128];
data[0] = '\0'; //null terminate so we don't print garbage

for( ; ; ) {
    //get a chunk of data off the FIFO buffer
    const int uart_num = UART_NUM_2;
    int length = 0;
    IotLogInfo( "preread" );
    length = uart_read_bytes(uart_num, data, 10, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS); //read 10 bytes or time out after a second.

    if(length == -1)
        IotLogInfo( "read reported error! -1" );

    //did we rx anything?
    if(length > 0){
        data[length] = '\0'; //null terminate the string
        IotLogInfo( "Rx: %i bytes", length );
        IotLogInfo( "Rx: %s ", data );
    }
    else{
        IotLogInfo( "rx no data" );
    }
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}
```

For some reason char 2 and 3 of the transmitted string "UVW" are getting messed with, even if the buffer holds more than a single transmission:

```
122 4911 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][49110] preread

123 5011 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][50110] Rx: 3 bytes

124 5011 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][50110] Rx: U⸮⸮ 

126 5011 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][50110] preread

127 5111 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][51110] Rx: 3 bytes

128 5111 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][51110] Rx: U⸮⸮ 

130 5111 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][51110] preread

131 5510 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][55100] Rx: 12 bytes

132 5510 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][55100] Rx: U⸮⸮U⸮⸮U⸮⸮U⸮⸮ 

134 5510 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][55100] preread

135 5710 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][57100] Rx: 6 bytes

136 5710 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][57100] Rx: U⸮⸮U⸮⸮ 

138 5710 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][57100] preread

139 5910 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][59100] Rx: 6 bytes

140 5910 [_readSerialForM] [INFO ][DEMO][59100] Rx: U⸮⸮U⸮⸮
```

"UVW" should be 0x55 x56 x57 but it appears it's being interpreted as "0x55 0xD5 0xFD", what's even weirder is if I send "UUU" to the serial which should be "0x55 0x55 0x55" it arrives as "0x55 0x55 0xF5", which is very weird as byte #2 isn't being malformed when its a repeat of the byte before it.

I have independently verified the transmission with an arduino and it reads perfectly. So I am very confused.

Im sure this is a fairly simple error on my part. However I cannot figure out what it is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What baud rate are you using? What device is on the transmitting end (a microcontroller, PC)?

Comment: I am transmitting from an Arduino Uno, I would like 115200 but I have tried as low as 9600 and this had zero effect.

Comment: Baud rate is one parameter, what about parity etc? Have also a look on the electrics: Ground connection? 5V vs. 3.3V? Wires mixed up? I noticed you receive only wrong bytes in which bits flipped from 0 to 1, but not in the other way.

Comment: Well done good sir. The issue was parity, Arduinos are by default to none, and the code I was using for the UART driver in FreeRTOS was even. this correction made all the difference. For the record, vcc was good and they shared a common ground.

Thank you very much - that was 2 days of pain you have released me from, would you like to claim the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serial interface must be configured correctly. The settings on both ends
must be the same.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Settings)
writes

> Many settings are required for serial connections used for asynchronous start-stop communication, to
> select **speed**, **number of data bits** per character, **parity**, and **number of stop bits** per character.
>
> (...)
>
> Often if the settings are entered incorrectly the connection will not be dropped;
> however, any data sent will be received on the other end as nonsense.

If the receiver sees a bad bit pattern on the wire it should raise "framing error" or "parity error".
However some errors cannot be detected and often those error states are simply ignored.

Another great source of problems with the serial interface is on the electric side.
The traditional RS232 comes with voltages up to +/-15V. In contrast, micro-controllers prefer classic logic signals (3.3V or 5V).
Mixing up the wires may allow *some* communication in one direction.
To rule out this complex you should check the signals with a multimeter or, even better, an oscilloscope.